# ag grid styles are not working after installation

Tags: angular

this is my dashboard.component.html

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

this is my dashboard.component.ts

```
columnDefs = [
    { field: 'Date', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'Time Elapsed', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'UOID', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'Claim', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'Cust Name', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'Cust Mobile', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'City', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'Service', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'Amount', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'Online Received', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'Pay Mode', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'Pay Status', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'Order Status', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'Pilot', sortable: true, filter: true },
    { field: 'Action', sortable: true, filter: true }
];
rowData = [];
```

this is my dashboard.module.ts

```
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
@NgModule({
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
],
imports: [
    CommonModule, 
    NgbCarouselModule, 
    NgbAlertModule, 
    DashboardRoutingModule, 
    StatModule, 
    AgGridModule.withComponents([])
],
declarations: [
    DashboardComponent, 
    TimelineComponent, 
    NotificationComponent, 
    ChatComponent
] }) export class DashboardModule {}
```

this is my dashboard.component.scss

```
@import  "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import  "~ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

[the output what i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Py1.png)

i am using SB admin bs4 dashboard. i don't no why this issue is not resolving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding Ag grid's css to `dashboard.component.scss`, move those imports to your `styles.scss` or include them in the `styles` array of your `angular.json` like below:

```
"styles":[
 "src/styles.scss",
 "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
 "node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css",
]
```

Comment: Glad to hear that, would u mind to upvote and accept my answer.